# react JSX.Element: соединить массив строк и теги как разделитель

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

подскажите как решить покомпактнее и поэлегантнее следующую задачу:

есть массив строк

```
let texts: string[];
```

надо на выходе получить JSX код в котором между строками будет стоять разделитель `<br />`

конечно можно сделать так:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: texts.join("<br />")}} />;
```

но мне кажется это все таки извратом, забиванием микроскопом гвозди и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

так?

```
<div>
   {arr.map(e => [e,<br/>])}
</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]